# How to understand the induction motor datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, induction-motor

I have got the below given datasheet for a three phase induction motor

[image]

and I have been attempting to understand its content. For me only the last column named *continuous point A* is clear - it describes the nominal operating point of the machine. But for example the column named *start* is unclear for me.

Based on its name I guess it should describe the starting operating point of the machine. But I don't understand why there is the stator frequency \$20\,\mathrm{Hz}\$ because at the startup the stator frequency is equal to the slip frequency which should be (based on the mentioned slip \$10.55\,\%\$) \$\frac{10.55}{100}\cdot 60 = 6.33\,\mathrm{Hz}\$. Can anybody help me
understand the content of the *start* column?

Comment: As this thing is clearly for a railway locomotive, I think you need more specialist advice than you can find here. The start column describes the ratings when starting from standstill, pulling a train (e.g. you cannot exceed 180V while pulling 500A to generate the high torque necessary, at low (20Hz) frequency and high slip. While that much is clear, designing a VFD to meet these conditions would be well beyond me.